# Change slelected cell of UITableView with Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Hi I have `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` classes 
I want when user click on cell change title of cell 
How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: Show your cell code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as! CellClassName

    cell.titleLbl = //////  suppose here the outlet is titleLbl

    // reflect this to model array to avoid reusing issues when you scroll
}
```